# Opening an Asp.Net MVC 4 web application in a IPhone with full screen hiding all the status bars, address bars of the browser

Tags: ios, iphone, asp.net-mvc, html

I am completely new to IOS development and I have developed an Asp.Net MVC 4 web application.

Now All I wan to do is I would like an app which shows my web site in full screen mode when opened in an IPhone hiding all the status bar, address bars and should ask a user to add the app to home screen when opened in an IPhone for the first time.

My Mobile Styles CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left,
    header .float-right {
        float: none;
        /*background-color:aliceblue;*/
    }

    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        /*background-color:aliceblue;*/
    }

    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #login ul {
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0;
        }

            #login a:hover {
                color: #333;
            }

    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

Is there any simple way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a webapp go full screen in iOS, you just need to add the meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

But, bear in mind, that if you do this, you are telling iOS that this is actually a web *application*, not just a mobile-optimized website. You'll be responsible for *all* navigation (back button, etc.). Basically, your web app should look and function like a native app, just on the web.

As far as adding to home screen goes, you cannot do this programatically. The user must actually manually add to home screen using the UI in MobileSafari. If you just want to prompt them to do that, then all you're talking about is a bit of HTML, styled however you like with some message. Then, you can use the boolean `window.navigator.standalone` to test whether or not the user is running in web app mode (and thus has already added your app to the home screen) to decide whether to hide or show the message via JS.

Also, bear in mind from a styling perspective, that iOS reports device and viewport width based on a 1x scale. That is to say an iPhone with a retina display has 640 horizontal pixels, but will report 320.

Comment: Where you add any meta tag: within the `<head>` element of your document.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below links settings, so that when ever you open it looks like native app instead of web browser app in iOS

http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/

If it answered , Please check right mark on left side to answered

Comment: Thanks, but should I add all those meta tags to the CSS in my MVC application or somewhere else?

Comment: meta tags are must to understand for apple, css changes is up to you